# Moshi error Expected name at path $.foo.bar

Tags: moshi

This Moshi error message:
`com.squareup.moshi.JsonEncodingException: Expected name at path $.foo.bar`

is not really very helpful in identifying the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Turns this is due to a trailing comma in the JSON.

There is [a fix in the works](https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/580) but i the meantime it might be helpful to document this here as Googling for the error message did not immediately lead me to the PR.

Comment: Any update here? how did you fit trailing commas issue with Moshi?